# How to customize Docbook with stylesheet ? Where do I find good resources?

Tags: docbook, docbook-xsl

I have to make some form of documentation of the projects I did , along with screenshots etc , and I'd like to make it less plain , so I tried adding CSS to my file , but it didn't work . After some browsing I found out that XSL or XSLT would be needed for this , which I never used , and couldn't find any good tutorial / documentation / examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish different parts of DocBook - authoring and processing (output result).

### Authoring

DocBook authoring is quite straigthforward - to get the best result use special GUI XML editors like [XMLMind XML Editor](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/) or [OxygenXML Author](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author.html) instead of plain text editors (I'm not affiliated in any way with XMLMind or Oxygen). Of course, you can ask, why I mentioned the authoring tools instead of customization itself and how these tools are related to customization? The answer is: any XML editor itself can be fully customized in a way, you need it for a productive work. There are mostly nothing related to DocBook XSL Stylesheets there but any editor ***can*** be customized to get the most appropriate result for authoring. And many parts of this customization are related to XSLT/XPath.

### Processing

This part fully depends on your knowledge of XSLT field and, in the same time, what result you want to get (expect). DocBook stylesheets were designed to get a result (output files) irrespective of your XSLT knowledge BUT the result complexity will be fully depend on the level of your knowledge.
Here are a simple list to get know you where you need to go:

1. If you know nothing about XSLT - you get the default result out of box.
2. If you are ready to make a tiny dig into DocBook parameters and tune them - you get the result more suitable for your needs. I.e. you can tune your page font for PDF (`body.font.master`), choose, what document headings include in TOC (`generate.toc`), etc. You need only one file to tune: `<docbook-xsl-distro-dir>/<output_type>/param.xsl`, where `docbook-xsl-distro-dir` - is your directory with DocBook XSL Stylesheets, `<output_type>` - type of output result you need to get (`fo` > print, `html` > html). To find out what each parameter is suitable for, you can use either [DocBook XSL reference](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.78.1/doc/) or/and (recommended!) the book **DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide** by Bob Stayton (available [online](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/)).
3. If you are ready to dig into the depths of a customization - you need to get really complex result for your output. In that case you need:

   - to get know XSLT (DocBook XSL Stylesheets are written in XSLT 1.0). I would recommend **XSLT Quickly** (from [Manning publishing](https://www.manning.com/books/xslt-quickly));
   - to read **DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide** throughly;
   - to get know HTML or XSL:FO (depend on output).